# "Disk is starting to degrade. New SMART event detected."

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, event-viewer

[image]

When I look at Event Viewer I find an error that bothers me:
"Disk is starting to degrade. New SMART event detected."

This PC is brand new, so why am I getting the degrading message?

Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLQ1T0HBLB-00BH1
Disk serial: PRIVATE.
event id 7002

Comment: Sometimes 'new' disks fail early, If its a brand new system, it is probably under warranty, and its probably worth checking if you can get it replaced

Comment: Thank you  
Journeyman Geek
I meant to add the update to this question: 
UPDATE I took the PC to BestBuy’s Geek Squad and they replaced the SSD from the Samsung brand to a new SK Hynix brand disk. Please help me check the Event Viewer for signs of event number 7002 and see if the issue has been fixed.

Comment: See also: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000034272/memory-and-storage.html

Comment: Don't add further info down here. Instead, EDIT your question to update and improve it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP had the faulty hardware replaced under warranty. Issue is no longer reproducible.

Comment: The hardware failure was also 6 months ago with a disk that isn’t even installed